# Nginx log_format not updating with new formatting

Tags: nginx

I am trying to update the format for nginx logs, but nothing I do has been working. Logging just keeps the same default logging pattern.
Here is what I have so far in nginx.conf in the http block:

```
   log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
```

I have also had the log format in this pattern as well:

```
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user xxx[$time_local]xxx '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

I've tried changing the name and adding a separate log inside the server block referencing the log_format name, neither of which worked. Here is the pattern I used inside the server block for my site:
`access_log /var/log/nginx/site-access.log main;`

I ran `nginx -T | grep log_format` and confirmed the only log_format present in my configuration is the one set in nginx.conf, yet no matter what I try, the logging format doesn't change.